# MS SQL query to calculate average monthly unique visitors

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I made MSSQL query that calculates total unique IP address and total IP records for past 30 days.

```
SELECT count(IPAddress) AS totalPageHits, count(DISTINCT IPAddress) AS totalVisitors, count(DateTime)
FROM recordTable
WHERE DateTime > GETDATE()-30
```

Now I am having a hard time to calculate average daily page hits and average daily unique visitors.
I have tried to use `AVG` but it gives me an error message saying "Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator." 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd need to group on an appropriate date interval...

Comment: `VARCHAR` datatype cannot be averaged, you need to use `int` or `bigint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  AVG(HitCount) as AverageHits,
    AVG(UniqueHitCount) As AverageUniqueHits
FROM
(
SELECT  COUNT(IPAddress) as HitCount,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) as UniqueHitCount,
        DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), DateTime) as Day
FROM tblHitCounter
WHERE DateTime > GETDATE() - 30
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), DateTime)
) sub
```

Comment: It worked! thank you so much for your help. Iv spend many hours trying to Google it and figure this thing out.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you... I've had to do a lot of SQL reporting over the years :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to group this by day and then do the averages:

```
select avg(totalPageHits) as avgDailyTotalPageHits,
       avg(totalVisitors) as avgDailyTotalVisitors
from (SELECT cast(DateTime as date) as thedate,
             count(IPAddress) AS totalPageHits,
             count(DISTINCT IPAddress) AS totalVisitors, count(DateTime) as cnt
      FROM recordTable
      WHERE DateTime > GETDATE()-30
      group by cast(DateTime as date)
     ) t
```

Comment: Yours is the correct answer - I had a brain-fart: avg(count(...)) would always equal that number, if it worked. Aggregate functions cannot be nested.

Comment: Can you please also tell me what is the {t} stands for. Because I get an error saying "No column name was specified for column 4 of 't'." Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - (Re you comment on the now deleted answer..) Fyi, ColdFusion just hands off SQL to your database. So supported operations depend on your database type and driver as usual.

Comment: @crashtestxxx - The `t` is a table alias. The error probably means you need to add a *column* alias to the count: `count(DateTime) AS NeedsAnAliasHere`